# SoftwareSerial Struggles

Tags: softwareserial, esp8266

Just trying to understand and use the SoftwareSerial

I want to connect a WiFi Module (ESP8266)
If I send an AT command to the module I would like to print a response on my pc screen in the serial monitor

Some example code it tried

```
   SoftwareSerial dbgSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
   void setup()
   {
     // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
     Serial.begin(57600);
     Serial.setTimeout(5000);
     dbgSerial.begin(9600); //can't be faster than 19200 for softserial
     dbgSerial.println("ESP8266 Demo");
     //test if the module is ready
     Serial.println("AT+RST");
     delay(1000);
     if(Serial.find("ready"))
     {
       dbgSerial.println("Module is ready");
```

I would like to receive ready in the serial

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are swapping the use of `Serial` and `dbgSerial`. I think you mean to use `Serial` to print to the computer and `dbgSerial` to communicate with your module. `Serial.println` should display the message in the terminal on your computer.